# AWS Openstack Connectfailure from Openstack client

Tags: amazon-web-services, timeout, openstack

I have OpenStack installed in an AWS EC2 instance with a Cirros image. Accessing the horizon dashboard via the Public IP/DNS lists all the API with the internal (Private IP) of 10.x.x.xxx.
When running OpenStack client commands from an external server, I get the below error.

> "keystoneauth1.exceptions.connection.ConnectFailure: Unable to
>   establish connection to http://10.x.x.xxx:5000/v3/endpoints?:
>   HTTPConnectionPool(host='10.x.x.xxx', port=5000): Max retries exceeded
>   with url: /v3/endpoints (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110]
>   Connection timed out',))"

where the 10.x.x.xxx is the internal/private IP of OpenStack (Ocata). The below is the command that fails.....

```
"openstack --os-auth-url http://externalIP:5000/v3 --debug server list"
```

**Here are details of my setup:-**

Environment - AWS EC2 with RHEL 7.x

Openstack - Ocata

Openstack Image - Cirros0.3.4

For some reason, OpenStack seems to map the internal IP while making a call to the external IP/DNS. Do we need to do some config changes to fix this? Please help.

Comment: Assuming you can establish a connection to openstack _internally_, what does `openstack endpoint list | grep keystone` display? Even if a service is listening on one of these external addresses, it will continue to use what is defined inside of keystone's endpoints to fulfill subsequent requests. You may need to consider proxying your requests through to the end services, or connecting through some alternative means, e.g. VPN.

Comment: If your setup is alright make sure you have opened the port 5000 using the security groups for your instances, also check the firewall in the keystone host.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the openstackclient from an external host, you need to edit the environment file (likely openrc or stackrc) to reflect all of the external IPs for the external URLs. You will also need to make sure that the security groups are setup to allow access to/from your services. If your environment files still have 10.X addresses in them, you will be misdirected at some point after authenticating and getting the token.